# Task module (popup) in MS Teams bot opening Bot's App store page when logged in via browser

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, task-module

I have created a Teams Bot, which is installed in the team by any of the team's members. The bot then sends the messages to other team members as per further functionality. I am using Adaptive controls. On one AdaptiveAction(Button) click I am opening a popup using the task module to display my webpage. It's all working fine in the MSTeams app. But if the user is logged in via browser in MSTeams clicking on this button opens the app store page for the bot. It is working for the user who has installed the bot.
Is this the Expected behavior that if the user has not installed the bot, task module popups won't work for them in the browser?

**Update:**
Task module popup is supposed to get open if the bot is installed in the teams scope. Hence If one of the team member installs the bot in a team and other members just received the notification from the bot, they should be able to see the popup as bot is installed in the team, of which they are part of. But instead the app store page is displayed everytime the user clicks on a button to open the popup.

Comment: To use Task Modules, the user needs to have the Teams app with the bot installed or have access to the bot through a personal or team scope. If the user has not installed the bot or doesn't have access to it, they won't be able to interact with the Task Modules.

Comment: Thannk you @Sayali-MSFT for confirming that.

Answer (score 0):

To use Task Modules, the user needs to have the Teams app with the bot installed or have access to the bot through a personal or team scope. If the user has not installed the bot or doesn't have access to it, they won't be able to interact with the Task Modules.

Comment: I have a question regarding team scope. I have updated the question description to elaborate.

Comment: If Possible, could you please share some code snippets and small video so that we can try to repro from our end.